# Template convenience constructor for inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm not entirely sure that I'm choosing the right approach here, so I'll sketch out the problem first:

I need a base class (could be abstract) that holds a convenience constructor for all it's children that returns a static instance of that child plus accepts a parameter of type `boost::tuple<std::string>` or `boost::tuple<short, int>`.

What my base class looks like:

```
class BaseClass{

public:

    template<typename TCLASS, typename TUPLE>
    static TCLASS* createPacketFromStruct(TUPLE s){
        TCLASS* p = new TCLASS();
        p->structure = s;
        p->createMessageFromStruct();
        return p;
    }
};
```

But I cannot get a static instance from that template.

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me. Why is `createPacketFromStruct` a (static) member of the class and not some free function? Is `TCLASS` derived from `BaseClass`? Is `structure` private? Also: `boost::tuple` or `boost::tuple` makes no sense.

Comment: I want to use it as a constructor like BaseClass* c = BaseClass::creasePacketFromStruct(...); structure is indeed private and changes from child to child; I edited the text (got lost) according to your suggestions.

Comment: Then what is your problem? What do you mean by "I cannot get a static instance from that template"? (You should also take `TUPLE&& s` as a parameter and use `p->structure = std::forward<TUPLE>(s);`)

Comment: thanks for the hint to std::forward. sadly for this part I'm on GCC 4.2 (i know, i stated C++11) - any suggestions how to move the tuple instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call the function like so:

```
MyClass* myClass = BaseClass::template createPacketFromStruct<MyClass,MyTuple>(s);
```

If you want the compiler to infer the template parameters, change the signature of the function to take an additional parameter of type `TCLASS**` and call it like so:

```
MyClass* myClass;
BaseClass::template createPacketFromStruct(&myClass, s);
```

(not sure if `template` is really needed, maybe `BaseClass::createPacketFromStruct(&myClass, s);` works as well)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is how to call the method you wrote? In that case, the following should be easier than the other answer:

```
MyClass* myClass = BaseClass::createPacketFromStruct<MyClass>( s );
```

The `template` keyword is not needed as `BaseClass` is not itself a template. Also, you don't need to specify the second template parameter.